# What to call someone who always sincerely shows on the outside how and what he feels on the inside?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology

So, this person is very open, honest and brave to display his vulnerabilities and feelings (because that's what feels natural for him, and as a good thing, to do) whether he's out in public, with strangers, or not. He's being particularly open about his feelings and vulnerabilities, even when it may not be asked for or necessary to do so. There is nothing fake or deceiving about this person. You're always directly connected to whom this person really is.

Comment: Are we describing someone here, or are we calling up a popular astrological narrative about a type of person?

Comment: It's all about a word or expression that fits with the meaning as described above.

Comment: You might say this person is very extrovert

Comment: @GroundZero extroverted*, or they are an extrovert.

Comment: He would be called 'Ernest'

Comment: I disagree entirely that extroverted fits here. Extroverted has a very particular meaning that has to do with being "outgoing" and enjoying larger social gatherings. One does not have to wear one's heart on one's sleeve or be emotionally transparent to be extroverted, and many extroverts are not like this.

Comment: Not a single word, but "Wears his heart on his sleeve" is a phrase used to describe somebody like that. The emphasis there is mostly on how openly they display their feelings, not so much on how genuine those feelings are (though you wouldn't use it to describe somebody projecting false feelings)

Answer (score 30):

A ***[genuine](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/genuine?s=t)*** person fits also.

> free from pretense, affectation, or hypocrisy; sincere: *a genuine person.*

It can also be applied to personal attributes like feelings, sympathy etc.

Answer (score 29):

A *transparent person* may be a possible definition.

[Transparent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Transparent):

> - easily understood; manifest; obvious.
> - candid; frank; open.

[Being transparent:](http://coachwithheart.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/223/)

> Like a looking glass into our soul. Often it is something that isn’t done. It is a way to keep our true self from being seen by others. Being transparent and showing your inner light to others is not something everyone does.

Comment: +1. This seems the most fitting, as it focuses on the (over-)openness of the person, not the honesty or the like. The only possible problem for this is just that it doesn't readily imply active openness, which is prominent in the question description.

Answer (score 27):

Someone who does not hide their feelings is said to ***"Wear their heart on their sleeve"***, or for a single-word description, the person can be said to be ***"guileless"***, meaning there is no insincerity or pretense to them.

> As defined in the Google Dictionary:
>
> **Guileless**: "devoid of guile; innocent and without deception."

Comment: Are you not mixing different notions here? My own inclination would have been to use 'transparent', since that seems to answer the question and is morally neutral. 'Wearing one's heart on one's sleeve' carries negative tones suggesting that a person constantly makes a show of their humanitarian nature. Similarly 'guileless' is morally evaluative.

Comment: But I agree that the question was posed in moral terms.

Comment: @WS2 I wouldn't associate wearing one's heart upon one's sleeve with showing off humanitarian sides. To me it just means being unable to conceal one's feelings (for better or worse). _Transparent_, on the other hand, I would associate with someone who has ulterior motives—someone you can see right through and who is the exact opposite of honest.

Comment: I'm confused @WS2, I don't see anywhere in the question where morality or connotation were of a concern to the OP.  :-s

Comment: The question is replete with terms of morality. Words and expressions like 'honest', 'brave', 'nothing fake or deceiving' all have moral implications. These may all be particularly relevant if you are the astrological writer for a tabloid newspaper, doing signs of the zodiac, but if you are a social worker writing a report on a young offender appearing before a court, such loaded language is best avoided.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet This question of 'transparency' when used metaphorically, is interesting. People hold polar opposite ideas about what it means.

Comment: @WS2 "'Wearing one's heart on one's sleeve' carries negative tones suggesting that a person constantly makes a show of their humanitarian nature"

I've never heard it used with the connotation you mentioned (either being a humanitarian or being a self-righteous humanitarian).  Wiktionary [defines it](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wear_one%27s_heart_on_one%27s_sleeve) as, "To be very transparent, open, or forthright about one's emotions", which I think is exactly right.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen I may be wrong about this, but my impression is that in Britain, (where it is perhaps less fashionable 'to wear one's heart on one's sleeve') that the term is more often used as a criticism and an indication of sentimentality.

Comment: @WS2: The original description of OP does seem to me a bit negative, though. At any case, I think *transparent* is better than *guileless*, since from the definition *guileless* seems to focus on the person being blameless, it doesn't describe the (over-)openness.

Comment: @justhalf, the definition of "innocent" used in the definition of "guileless" does not mean blameless in that sense.  As MWO's definition 2a states: "lacking experience with the world and the bad things that happen in life."

Comment: I like "wearing one's heart on one's sleeve" but not "guileless", since it suggests that guile lies at the heart of the opposite, arguably more normal, behavior. Concealing one's feelings is often appropriate and I think "guile" has too many negative connotations to describe it even by implication, as here.

Comment: Looks like my two choices bring out some polarity amongst our community @Two-BitAlchemist! :-)

Answer (score 13):

I would say you answered your own question in the title: the word I would use is *sincere*.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a term with a higher degree of sincerity, including being particularly open about your feelings and vulnerabilities, even when it may not be asked for or necessary to do so. Not being open about them doesn't make you insincere, I think.

Comment: "Not being open about them doesn't make you insincere" -> This is precisely what's not so correct with *guileless*. I think *transparent* fits better for your question, since it focuses on the (over-)openness. However it doesn't imply *active openness*, though.

Answer (score 9):

> an open book

although to me this implies the negative aspects like naivety

Answer (score 5):

While its antonym, *disingenuous* is much more commonly heard, you might consider **[ingenuous](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ingenuous)**

> candid; frank; straightforward

Comment: Yeah, but look at definition #1:
naive, artless, or innocent

Comment: @JATerroba Absolutely. You would need context to clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Unfiltered is another way to express this.  It expresses no connotations about the morality or sentiment expressed, it only expresses that the person shows precisely what is on the inside, whatever it is.

Answer (score 3):

*Radically honest* would seem to describe what you are talking about, although it's not a single word. <sup>1</sup>

Some people on the autistic spectrum also display radical honesty without regard to social context or social consequences. <sup>2</sup>

[1] [Radical Honesty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_Honesty)

[2] [Caetextia](http://caetextia.com/pages/examples.html)